# How to get defined preprocessor symbols for given compilation in roslyn analyser

Tags: roslyn-code-analysis

Inside roslyn diagnostic (analyzer) - is there a way to know what preprocessor symbols are defined for a current compilation?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `CSharpCompilation` class in Roslyn to get a list of preprocessor symbols that are defined for a current compilation.
to get current compilation :

```
CSharpCompilation compilation = (CSharpCompilation)context.Compilation;
```

to get the list of preprocessor symbols that are defined

```
ImmutableArray<SymbolDisplayPart> preprocessorSymbols = compilation.PreprocessorSymbolNames;
```

Comment: PreprocessorSymbolNames is inseide CSharpParseOptions, but you got me into the right direction, thanks

Comment: If you correct your answer to use proper class, I will accept it